# How to Update Executed table result into the same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table `tbl_Dist` with Column names `District` and `DistCode`, there were many duplicate values in the District table so i have removed all the duplicates value using this statement:

```
select distinct District from tbl_Dist;
```

its done, but i am not getting how to update the results of the above executed query to the table `tbl_Dist`?

Comment: doesn't DistCode is primary key in your table ?

Comment: Do you mean something like this: `DELETE FROM tbl_Dist
WHERE Destrict IN (select distinct District from tbl_Dist)`?

Comment: NO, DistCode is not primary key

Comment: so you don't have primary key in your table 
and does it DistCode is int ?

Comment: @Blobonat- Ahh sorry i am new to sqlserver, can you please tell me what happen  if i excuted the above querry which u sent ??

Comment: @MahmoudZakal - Yes its INT.

Comment: @shivanandsb This query will delete all rows with the same `District` as your query returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can as the below:

```
-- Move temp table
SELECT DISTINCT District INTO TmpTable FROM tbl_Dist
-- Delete all data
DELETE FROM tbl_Dist
-- Insert data from temp table
INSERT INTO tbl_Dist
SELECT * FROM TmpTable
```

**Updated**

Firstly, run this query. You will have a temp table with distinct data of main table (tbl_Dist)

```
-- Move temp table
SELECT DISTINCT District INTO TmpTable FROM tbl_Dist
```

Then run the below query to delete all data

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Dist
```

Finally, run the below query to insert all distinct data to main table.

```
-- Insert data from temp table
INSERT INTO tbl_Dist
SELECT * FROM TmpTable
```

Comment: Yes it's working but how to update the results into the table ? If i right clicked on the table name and selected edit top 200 rows District column is blank..

Comment: @shivanandsb Not clear. Can you show sample and expected data?

Comment: From tble TmpTable i want to copy the column District to table tbl_DIst  , i have tried this 'UPDATE tbl_Dist
SET tbl_Dist.District = dbo.TmpTable.District
FROM dbo.TmpTable
INNER JOIN tbl_Dist
ON (dbo.TmpTable.DistCode= tbl_Dist.DistCode);'

Comment: i have created DistCode column in TmpTable also for joining.

Comment: No need join. Insert all distinct data to temp table. Delete all data in main table Then insert all data to main table from temp table.

Comment: its showing error like "An explicit value for the identity column in table 'tbl_Dist' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON"....

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_Dist (District) SELECT * FROM TmpTable`

Answer (score 1):

You need `Delete` not `Update`

```
;with cte as
(
Select row_number() over(partition by District order by (select null)) as rn,* 
From yourtable
)
Delete from cte where Rn > 1
```

To check the records that will be deleted use this.

```
;with cte as
(
Select row_number() over(partition by District order by (select null)) as rn,* 
From yourtable
)
Select * from cte where Rn > 1
```

Comment: if i executed this querry, all the rows will get delete apart from first row right????

Comment: @shivanandsb - yes before that check the records that will be deleted through the `select`

Comment: could you explain exactly what this script gonna do 
it has been written in pro way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep this query you can keep it in a view the write an update query through that view.The table will be updated

Answer (score 0):

try this script

```
DELETE FROM tbl_Dist 
WHERE District = District 
AND DistCode > DistCode
```